# Unable to deploy gitlab cicd

Tags: gitlab, cicd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r394.png)
People ask me, I click "play" button deploy cicd gitlab but it doesn't work.

- I have checked the source code and the file "gitlab-ci.yml" has no problem at all. Before that 1 time I was still using them normally until this new update version, I can't use them anymore.
  Thanks